# Embedding VLC plugin on HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, vlc

I have a html file (`getStream.html`) that takes a stream from a certain url and show it. The code is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>Vids</title>
    <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload='player("http://mystreamaddress:8080");'>

<div id="player">
    <object type="application/x-vlc-plugin" 
      id="vlcplayer" 
      width="864px"
      height="540px" 
      classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921">  
      <param name="Volume" value="100" />
      <param name="AutoPlay" value="true" />
      <param name="AutoLoop" value="false" />
    </object>
</div>

<div id="controls">
  <input type="button" onclick="play();" value="Play" />
  <input type="button" onclick="pause();" value="Pause" />
  <input type="button" onclick="stop();" value="Stop" />
  <input type="button" onclick="mute();" value="Mute" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var vlc = document.getElementById("vlcplayer");
    function player(vid) {
    try {
        var options = new Array(":aspect-ratio=16:10", "--rtsp-tcp", ":no-video-title-show");
      var id = vlc.playlist.add(vid,'Video',options);
      vlc.playlist.playItem(id);
      vlc.video.fullscreen = true;
      //vlc.video.toggleFullscreen();
    }
    catch (ex) {
      alert(ex);
    }
    }       
    function mute(){
    vlc.audio.toggleMute();
  }

    function play(){
    vlc.playlist.play();
  }

    function stop(){
    vlc.playlist.stop();
  }

    function pause(){ 
    vlc.playlist.togglePause();
  } 

  function fullscreen(){
    vlc.video.toggleFullscreen();
  }

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

If I have this page on my pc and I try open it (using IE 7/8/9), all works good, but If put this page on my server, and then I access to it from a url like this: `http://myserver/direcortyOfMyhtmlFile/getStream.html`

the page is opened and the buttons are loaded, but I obtain the following error:

in IE8 and IE9:
[image: error in IE9, IE8]

That in english should be something like: "Impossible obtain the value of property 'add': object null or not defined"

In IE7:
[image]

These errors seems to refer to object in my html, but this is strange for me, because the same page works without problem locally.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question html5?

Comment: @Joseph82 What did you do to solve this?

Answer (score 7):

`test.html` is will be helpful for how to use VLC WebAPI.

`test.html` is located in the directory where VLC was installed.

**e.g.** `C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\sdk\activex\test.html`

The following code is a quote from the `test.html`.

**HTML:**

```
<object classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921" width="640" height="360" id="vlc" events="True">
  <param name="MRL" value="" />
  <param name="ShowDisplay" value="True" />
  <param name="AutoLoop" value="False" />
  <param name="AutoPlay" value="False" />
  <param name="Volume" value="50" />
  <param name="toolbar" value="true" />
  <param name="StartTime" value="0" />
  <EMBED pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"
    width="640"
    height="360"
    toolbar="true"
    loop="false"
    text="Waiting for video"
    name="vlc">
  </EMBED>
</object>
```

**JavaScript:**

You can get vlc object from `getVLC()`.
It works on IE 10 and Chrome.

```
function getVLC(name)
{
    if (window.document[name])
    {
        return window.document[name];
    }
    if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")==-1)
    {
        if (document.embeds && document.embeds[name])
            return document.embeds[name];
    }
    else // if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft Internet")!=-1)
    {
        return document.getElementById(name);
    }
}

var vlc = getVLC("vlc");

// do something.
// e.g. vlc.playlist.play();
```

Answer (score 3):

I found this:

```
<embed type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"  width="100%"        
height="100%" id="vlc" loop="yes"autoplay="yes" target="http://10.1.2.201:8000/"></embed>
```

I don't see that in your code anywhere....  I think that's all you need and the target would be the location of your video...

and here is more info on the vlc plugin:
http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation%3aWebPlugin#Input_object

Another thing to check is that the address for the video file is correct....

Comment: I tried yet this solution, but works only for mozilla or chrome. I need to use IE. My code works good in IE, but only if I have the html file locally, on my pc. As said, if I put the file on my server and I recall it the strange problem appears. :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, IE and VLC don't really work right now...  I found this on the vlc forums:

```
VLC included activex support up until version 0.8.6, I believe. At that time, you could
access a cab on the videolan and therefore 'automatic' installation into IE and Firefox
family browsers was fine. Thereafter support for activex seemed to stop; no cab, no
activex component.

VLC 1.0.* once again contains activex support, and that's brilliant. A good decision in
my opinion. What's lacking is a cab installer for the latest version.
```

This basically means that even if you found a way to make it work, anyone trying to view the video on your site in IE would have to download and install the entire VLC player program to have it work in IE, and users probably don't want to do that. I can't get your code to work in firefox or IE8 on my boyfriends computer, although I might not have been putting the video address in properly... I get some message about no video output...

I'll take a guess and say it probably works for you locally because you have VLC installed, but your server doesn't.  Unfortunately you'll probably have to use Windows media player or something similar (Microsoft is great at forcing people to use their stuff!)

And if you're wondering, it appears that the reason there is no cab file is because of the cost of having an active-x control signed.

It's rather simple to have your page use VLC for firefox and chrome users, and Windows Media Player for IE users, if that would work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I found this piece of code somewhere in the web.
Maybe it helps you and I give you an update so far I accomodated it for the same purpose... Maybe I don't.... who the futt knows... with all the nogodders and dobedders in here :-/

```
function runVLC(target, stream)
{
var support=true
var addr='rtsp://' + window.location.hostname + stream
if ($.browser.msie){
$(target).html('<object type = "application/x-vlc-plugin"' + 'version =  
"VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"' + 'classid = "clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"' + 
'events = "true"' + 'id = "vlc"></object>')
}
else if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.webkit){
$(target).html('<embed type = "application/x-vlc-plugin"' + 'class="vlc_plugin"' + 
'pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"' + 'version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" ' + 
'width="660" height="372"' + 
'id="vlc"' + 'autoplay="true"' + 'allowfullscreen="false"' + 'windowless="true"' + 
'mute="false"' + 'loop="true"' + '<toolbar="false"' + 'bgcolor="#111111"' + 
'branding="false"' + 'controls="false"' + 'aspectRatio="16:9"' + 
'target="whatever.mp4"></embed>')
}
else{
support=false
$(target).empty().html('<div id = "dialog_error">Error: browser not supported!</div>')
}
if (support){
var vlc = document.getElementById('vlc')
if (vlc){
var opt = new Array(':network-caching=300')
try{
var id = vlc.playlist.add(addr, '', opt)
vlc.playlist.playItem(id)
}
catch (e){
$(target).empty().html('<div id = "dialog_error">Error: ' + e + '<br>URL: ' + addr + 
'</div>')
}
}
}
}
/* $(target + ' object').css({'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'}) */
```

Greets

Gee

I reduce the whole crap now to:

```
function runvlc(){
var target=$('body')
var error=$('#dialog_error')
var support=true
var addr='rtsp://../html/media/video/TESTCARD.MP4'
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")!=-1){
target.append('<object type = "application/x-vlc-plugin"' + 'version = "
VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2"' + 'classid = "clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"' + 
'events = "true"' + 'id = "vlc"></object>')
}
else if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie")==-1){
target.append('<embed type = "application/x-vlc-plugin"' + 'class="vlc_plugin"' + 
'pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"' + 'version="VideoLAN.VLCPlugin.2" ' + 
'width="660" height="372"' + 
'id="vlc"' + 'autoplay="true"' + 'allowfullscreen="false"' + 'windowless="true"' + 
'mute="false"' + 'loop="true"' + '<toolbar="false"' + 'bgcolor="#111111"' + 
'branding="false"' + 
'controls="false"' + 'aspectRatio="16:9"' + 'target="whatever.mp4">
</embed>')
}
else{
support=false
error.empty().html('Error: browser not supported!')
error.show()
if (support){
var vlc=document.getElementById('vlc')
if (vlc){
var options=new Array(':network-caching=300') /* set additional vlc--options */
try{ /* error handling */
var id = vlc.playlist.add(addr,'',options)
vlc.playlist.playItem(id)
}
catch (e){
error.empty().html('Error: ' + e + '<br>URL: ' + addr + '')
error.show()
}
}
}
}
};
```

Didn't get it to work in ie as well...
2b continued...

Greets

Gee