# VLC plugin can't work use JS API on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, vlc

I use VLC Media Player ActiveX on webapps to play audio, and use those HTML to embed VLC plugin:

```
<object id='vlc_player' controls='false' width='0' events='true' height='0' classid="clsid:9BE31822-FDAD-461B-AD51-BE1D1C159921"></object>
```

It can work well on Windows7 of IE, even IE7 mode. But can't work under WinXP, even IE8. All VLC objects are prompted undefined;

When i add 'src' attributes to designation the play source, it can work well, Only JS API can't work!

this is official document of VLC's Web plugin https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/

Comment: Xp is obsolete since few months now.

Comment: If you don't have the required ActiveX installed and registered in your machine, you'd need the `codebase` attribute pointing to the code.

Comment: @Teemu all of user know need install vlc player before use webapp, so, all of user installed and registered in his machine.

Comment: also we can play video directly with 'src' attributes, not use JS API, but now, we can't use JS API to control the player!

Comment: I was answerd to similar question here: [Embedding VLC plugin on HTML page][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28008227/4366193